# Unique=True in Form not throwing any error

Tags: django

I'm entering a duplicate value (already saved in another instance of the same model) in my form to test the unique=True attribute. form.is_valid() returns 'False', as expected, but I don't receive any prompt in the template. Shouldn't I get prompted something like "obj with this value already exists"? The page simply reloads... What am I missing?

**forms.py**

```
def update_route(request, pk):

    instance = Route.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RouteForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            instance.name = data['name']
            instance.priority = data['priority']
            instance.url = data['url']
            return redirect('campaigns:routes_list')

    form = RouteForm(instance=instance)

    context= {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "campaigns/route_form.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    priority = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_LEVEL, default=0, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField()
```

**Template**

```
<form  method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update_route()` view handles the condition in which the submitted form is valid (`form.is_valid()`), but not the condition in which the form is *invalid*.

The errors you are looking for are stored in the `form` object that you created with `RouteForm(request.POST)`. The errors are generated when the `is_valid()` method is called.

This form object needs to be added to the context dict and rerendered to the user for the errors to surface. But your code currently overwrites that object with `form = RouteForm(instance=instance)`, so the POST data and the related errors disappear.

One solution could be to handle it in the conditional statement:

```
if form.is_valid():
   ...
else:
   context = {'form': form}
   return render(request, "campaigns/route_form.html", context)
```

Another solution could be to create a conditional statement for GET requests, for example:

```
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form = RouteForm(instance=instance)
```

Comment: Thanks, the explanation was very useful. Makes sense!